# Is it possible to not use the static tag and still apply and display static files in Django?

Tags: django

What should be done to allow relative paths inside the static files to work without using the static tag?

I want to add HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files from a front-end developer
and have them work with Django without modifying them. As the front-end developer doesn't know django template language and it would be a lot of work to modify them myself.

Comment: yes why not, use the full path to your static files :)

Comment: @Exprator Where should I add the full path to the static files? I tried adding the path of the static files to `STATICFILES_DIRS` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Terahertz No you put the url to the static files in your htm templates: `"/static/style.css"`.

Comment: Yes that worked well, but it's still modification of the files. If possible I want to use the static files as they are, and maybe change how Django handles them.